# Inserting date into PostgreSQL: Columns from and to

Tags: database, postgresql

I can't insert a `date` into a PostgreSQL 9.6 table.

This is the INSERT Query:

```
INSERT INTO rates (idproperty, from, to, price)
VALUES (1, '2017-03-14', '2017-04-30', 130);
```

And that's the result:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO rates (idproperty, from, to, price)
```

The columns `from` and `to` are defined with the data type `date`.

Thanks

Comment: `from` and `to` are reserved keywords.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Is the same issue, but with different reserved keywords. Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`from` and `to` are reserved words in PostgreSQL. You need to escape them with `"`:

```
-- This fails:

test=# SELECT from FROM rates;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: SELECT from FROM rates;
                    ^

-- This works:

test=# SELECT "from" FROM rates;
 from 
------
(0 rows)
```

See list of reserved words: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was getting crazy ;-)

Answer (score 21):

I believe you have used postgresql reserved words - `from` and `to` to create your table. In order to use them in your query, they need to be enclosed in quotes `"`

Try it this way:

```
INSERT INTO rates (idproperty, "from", "to", price)
VALUES (1, '2017-03-14', '2017-04-30', 130);
```

Answer (score 0):

from and to is not a correct field it is reserved , please change to from_i for example and to_i